# Batch for loop - Program exits - Reg Query - Win 7

Tags: loops, batch-file, for-loop, registry

Problem: The below batch program exits when trying to run the 1st `for` loop, and `%file3%` txt file only has:

```
Displayname 
-------------
```

Need advice on why the for loop is not working please.

Partial output of REG query in 1st for loop in a text file:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\Adobe AIR
DisplayName    REG_SZ    Adobe AIR

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\Cisco AnyConnect Secure Mobility Client
DisplayName    REG_SZ    Cisco AnyConnect Secure Mobility Client 

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\CitrixOnlinePluginPackWeb
DisplayName    REG_SZ    Citrix Receiver

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\KLiteCodecPack_is1
DisplayName    REG_SZ    K-Lite Codec Pack 10.7.5 Basic

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\Mobile Broadband HL Service
DisplayName    REG_SZ    Mobile Broadband HL Service
```

Desired output in %file3%:

```
Displayname
-------------
Adobe AIR
Cisco AnyConnect Secure Mobility Client
Citrix Receiver
K-Lite Codec Pack 10.7.5 Basic
Mobile Broadband HL Service
```

Batch code:

```
@echo OFF
setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion 
set "Version_tool=v2"
Echo Version: %Version_tool%
Echo Modified 19/01/15 by xxx
SET "ComputerName=%computername%"
echo ComputerName is: %ComputerName%

SET "file3=%~dp0%computername%-programs_unsorted.txt"
echo File3 is: %file3%
If Exist %file3% Del %file3%

echo Displayname >> %file3%
echo ------------- >> %file3%

set "keyname=HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall"
echo keyname is: !keyname!

Rem === Problem is below - program exits when running for loop ===
For /f "usebackq tokens=* delims=" %%A in (`REG Query "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\" /V /F DisplayName /S /E`) do (
pause
set "DisplayName=%%A"
echo DisplayName is: !Displayname!
pause
set "Display_Substring=!DisplayName:~0,71!"
echo Display_Substring is: !Display_Substring!
pause

if not "!DisplayName:HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE=!"=="!DisplayName!" echo !DisplayName! >> %file3%

::if !DisplayName:~0,71!==HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\ (
::  echo skipping !DisplayName!
::) else (
::  echo !DisplayName! >> %file3%
::)
)
```

Comment: Use `if !DisplayName:~0,71!==` instead of `if %DisplayName:~1,71%=`. Note doubled `==` and `!` instead of `%`. `%DisplayName%` results to a constant value within all loop, particularly to an empty string... You could consider to test `if not "!DisplayName:HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE=!"=="!DisplayName!"` rather

Comment: @JosefZ I've updated the question - the 1st `for` loop still causes program to exit. The line is now: `if not "!DisplayName:HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE=!"=="!DisplayName!" echo !DisplayName! >> %file3%`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problems:

1) You specify `usebackq`, but you used single quotes, so FOR /F processes the string instead of the command. Drop the `usebackq` and the loop will process the command properly. The only time I ever use `usebackq` is when I am reading from a file whose path must be quoted, typically because of spaces.

2) Your IF statement is a mess:

- Your command uses normal expansion instead of delayed expansion, so it cannot see the value set within the loop.
- You used `=` but the comparison operator is `==`.
- Values should be quoted on both sides of the comparison when using delayed expansion substring operation within an IF statement, or you must escape the comma. I recommend the quotes (actually you don't even need the IF at all)

```
if "!DisplayName:~1,71!"=="yourValue..."
```

3) You want to exclude the summary line of output. The simplest solution is to pipe the output to FIND or FINDSTR and let it filter out lines you don't want. The pipe operator must be escaped within the IN() clause.

4) You can let FOR /F parse out the columns (tokens). You want the 3rd column, which contains spaces. None of the prior columns contain spaces, so you can use `tokens=2*`, which means capture the 2nd token in the first variable, and preserve everything after that in the second variable.

```
for /f "tokens=2*" %%A in (
  'REG Query "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall" /V /F DisplayName /S /E^|find "DisplayName"'
) do echo %%B>>"%file3%"
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. You have a typo in the `Reg` query - there should be a space after `/E`. However after this correction whilst the `Reg` command works, the `for` loop doesn't - program still exits.

Comment: Cosmetic bug: missing `do` in the command you provided, should be  `) do echo %%B` instead of `) echo %%B`. Severe  bug: piping `reg query` like `reg query hkcu\console|find "FaceName"` works but `for /F %G in ('reg query "hkcu\console"|find "FaceName"') do @echo %G` returns error `| was unexpected at this time.`

Comment: @JosefZ - The missing `DO` is a critical bug (not cosmetic), but trivial to fix. Thanks for pointing that out. Regarding the "serious bug" - as I said in my answer and had in my code, the pipe must be escaped when used in an `IN()` clause. I believe the only bug in my code was the missing `DO`.

Comment: @NickProwse - There is no need for a space after `/E`. Everything should now work sine I added the missing `DO`.